# insert values into a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to add dictionary values to my list of dictionaries whose keys are not unique but same to all the dictionaries.and these value are in turn again added to the google sheet under their respective columns(keys) in a particular index.

I initially thought I would make a list of keys and then the list of values to add and insert them..but I don't think that's the approach.
I'm stuck!

```
[`list of dictionaries`
 {"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
 {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
 {"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]
```

Comment: pretty confusing what you are trying to do, can you show a more clearer example

Comment: `lst.append(dct)` ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh i have a list of values to enter for a respective name say [jane,15], i want to insert this into the list of dictionaries as the next dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You need, create a list with the keys, like:

```
KEYS = ['name', 'age']
```

and for witch new values:

```
values = ['jane', 15]
```

make:

```
list_of_dictionaries.append(dict(zip(KEYS, values)))
```

Comment: say there is a key which has no value...like [{'name':'mathew','age':15,'class':10},{'name':'preet','age':12,'class':15}] and now i want to add another dictionary using argparse giving only name and age values as arguments,and class value would be none..how can i do that?